# Reason and impact regarding different-versioned packages in a conda environment

Tags: python, conda, pypi

When checking my conda environment by using "conda list", I saw that three versions of numpy have been installed. I am wondering the possible reason causing this and whether this will impact importing the right package in Python.

`numpy                     1.11.3                    <pip>
 numpy                     1.11.1                    <pip>
 numpy                     1.11.1                   py27_0`

Answer (score 1):

The state in which you are in, can be reproduced by:

```
(test) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ pip install numpy==1.11.1

(test) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ conda install numpy=1.11.1 -y

(test) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ pip install numpy==1.11.3

(test) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ conda list | grep numpy
numpy                     1.11.1                   py27_0  
numpy                     1.11.3                    <pip>
numpy                     1.11.1                    <pip>
```

Finding out which version of numpy you will actually end up using:

```
(test) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__"
1.11.3
```